# Why won't my timer reset every three days dynamically?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, debugging

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong in the logic of my code where I'm trying to make the timer reset every three days.  In the code below, I have the timer set to expire September 1, 2019, which's three days from now.

I want it to reset on its own to September 4, 2019, then September 7, 2019, etc.

What am I doing wrong & how can I rectify this?  A JSFiddle's also provided below.

https://jsfiddle.net/des6gjqa/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        p {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 60px;
            margin-top: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 1, 2019 9:45:00").getTime();
    while(countDownDate.valueOf() < Date.now()) {
        countDownDate = new Date(countDownDate.valueOf() + (3 * 24 * 60 * 1000)); // add 3 days to the start date
    }

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

        // Get today's date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();

        // Find the distance between now and the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

        // If the count down is over, write some text
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        }

        if(countDownDate.valueOf() <= Date.now()) {
            countDownDate = new Date(countDownDate.valueOf() + (3 * 24 * 60 * 1000));
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is less complex than what you are thinking. Consider the following:

- JavaScript is a client side language (for this example)
- The browser data (localStorage, cache, etc) can be easily manipulated.
- JavaScript execution stops when the page is closed.

> So, the only way to reset the timer every three days with what you are trying is to not close the window during three days. Because when you close it and visit the site once again, the timer will start from 0.

### What should you do?

The best approach to this is to have something running on a server. (i.E. PHP, Node.js, Python, Java, etc)
And  then, you should use a method to identify the user's machine like the IP address, a custom token (generated server side), etc.

This way, you could assign a cookie to the user visiting your site with a session ID and save in a database the starting date. By doing this, you can easily compare anytime the actual date with the start date anytime and then eval if the lapse is bigger than 3 days, show EXPIRED.

> *Because otherwise, the script you provided will start counting 3 days every time it is loaded.*

Comment: I got you, I had a feeling I needed some backend functionality for this.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

See k3llydev's answer for a more robust fix. If you wish for this code to be client side with the assumption that the webpage will be open for the entire duration, here I have made modifications to your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/as57fjuL/.

Essentially, it is just resetting the 'x' interval after clearing the interval and setting the date again. For simplicity, I have manually set the timeout to about 3 seconds (which can be changed by removing the line `countDownDate = new Date(Date.now().valueOf() + 5000);`).

Answer (score 0):

You miss second in your expression:
instead of (3 * 24 * 60 * 1000) you should use (3 * 24 * 60 *** 60** * 1000)